# Javascript - Multiple scope related questions

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

Please check the code in http://jsfiddle.net/4a42n8g8/. it alerts "undefined". Why? I have 2 questions in particular.

```
var a = 10;

function x() {
a = 20;
alert(this.a);
}

x();
```

1) Isn't the variable "a" within function x a global variable since it does not have a var prefix? Or is it that with or without var prefix, any variable within a function is not a global variable?

2) Since var a = 10 is defined outside the function, doesn't it make it a global variable? Or is it that all global variables SHOULD NOT have a var prefix?

Comment: try the same code in chrome console and you will get correct answer!

Comment: for opening chrome console press F12 while chrome is open and then press console in option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that jsfiddle is running your code within a function like the following:

```
window.onload=function(){
var a = 10;

function x() {
    a = 20;
    alert(this.a);
}

x();
}
```

Therefore, your `var a` is local to the `onload` function, but `this` inside of `x` points to  the global `window` object

If you change your fiddle settings to `No wrap - in <head>` (or in `<body>`), it will work as you expect. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/4a42n8g8/1/

**Question 1**

`var a` is not a global because it's within a function, if it was outside of any functions, it would be global.

**Question 2**

Same as question one, `var a` actually is defined in a function.

Comment: So, If the above question was asked in an interview, we would answer it with virtual No wrap, right?

Comment: Sp If you can answer and confirm my 2 questions, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your interview question. `virtual no wrap` doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: I meant, if the above question was asked in an interview(just the snippet), then we should be answering the question keeping in mind that there is no "window.onload...." right?

Comment: Or correct me if you think otherwise - 1) any variable outside or within a function, if does not have a var prefix is a global variable.

Comment: If it was asked in an interview, it would be asking what the value of `a` should be, and there is no indication that it is wrapped in a function.

Comment: @NikhilPai That is not true, if a variable is not prefixed with `var`, it may still not be global, if there is a variable with that name in the containing closures. That is exactly what happened when jsfiddle wrapped that code with `window.onload = function(){}`, `a` is not prefixed in `function x(){}` but it is not global, it's local to the `onload` function

Comment: @NikhilPai In short, you have determined a wrong scope for the `this` keyword. Don't get lost into those global or local variable things, google for some articles about `scope` and your question will be clarified.

Comment: @nquocnghia That is completely incorrect, the problem here is not `this`. `this` always points to the global scope in this example. The problem is the fact that the `var` declaration was inside of a function but the OP didn't realize that.

Comment: I meant the OP seems not to understand what `this` is referred as, so I suggested him to read about the scopes. But you're right btw.

Comment: @nquocnghia It may be that the OP doesn't understand how `this` gets assigned a value, but the question doesn't say anything indicating that, it's about why `a` is not global. That leads me to believe that they do know that `this.a` should be pointing to the global `a` variable

Comment: @nquocnghia @NikhilPai OP = Original Poster http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op So... do you or do you not understand why `this` points to the global scope within the `x` function?